# Return value type does not match function type when returning pointer to constant getter

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

So I'm having a little bit of problem with returning a pointer in a getter

Error:

```
Return value type does not match the function type'
```

My Class header:

```
class MyClass
{
    private:
        CustomModule clientModule;
        bool initialized;

    public:
        MyClass();

        CustomModule* getClientModule() const;
}
```

The Class cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"
MyClass::MyClass(){
    initialized = true;
}

CustomModule* MyClass::getClientModule() const{
    return &clientModule;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what the `const` means after `getClientModule()`?

Comment: @Yakk that the function may not change any value right?

Comment: that `this` is a pointer-to-`const` eithin the method, which is a bit stronger.

Answer (score 6):

A method with `const` at the end of it is a `const` method.  It is legal to call on a `const` instance of the object or through a `const` reference to the object, and it promises that it will not change the state of the object, *nor* will it be the route of permission to allow others to change the state of the object (basically, it won't change the state of the object, directly or indirectly).

Your `const` method returns a pointer to something within the object.  Within the `const` method, that sub-object is also `const`.  So a pointer to it is a pointer to a `const` instance.  You then return it as a non-`const` pointer, and the compiler complains.

This is correct, because if you returned a pointer to a non-`const` sub object from a `const` method, that method would be "acting as a way to change the state of the object indirectly".  Someone could take a `const` reference to your object, or a `const` instance, and get a pointer at the objects internal guts.  They could then modify the guts of the object.

So, in short, within a  `const` function, members are `const`, so your pointer is a pointer-to-`const`, but the return type is not.  Hence, compiler error.

Make a `const` getter that returns a pointer to const, and a non-`const` getter that returns a pointer-to-non-`const`.

In the header file:

```
CustomModule const * getClientModule() const;
CustomModule       * getClientModule();
```

and in the `.cpp` file:

```
CustomModule const* MyClass::getClientModule() const {
  return &clientModule;
}
CustomModule      * MyClass::getClientModule() {
  return &clientModule;
}
```

and your code should start working.

Comment: But I do need the pointer, so the only solution is to not make it const? Since what it points to isn't const

Comment: @PrivateerGerrit within that function, what it points to **is** `const`, as it is a `const` method.  To understand better, you could have a `const MyClass` that is actually `const`.  Then the data within it would be `const`, no?  And calling `getClientModule()` would be legal.  If it returned a pointer to non-`const`, it would violate `const` correctness.  A `const` method may not alter object state, nor be the permission method for others to do the same.

Answer (score 6):

My compiler gives a rather more helpful message:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘const CustomModule*’ to ‘CustomModule*’
```

Within a `const` member function, the object (and its members) are `const`; so you can't return a `const` pointer or reference to any member.

You need one or both of these overloads:

```
CustomModule const * getClientModule() const;
CustomModule       * getClientModule();
```

returning a `const` pointer when called on a `const` object, otherwise a non-`const` pointer.

Comment: I'll always need the pointer so technically the const one is useless then?
Also why do you also add const in front of the function name, is it any different from putting it in front of the CustomModule?

Comment: If you always need it non-const, then indeed you just want the non-const version. `CustomModule const` means exactly the same as `const CustomModule`; I like to put it after the thing it qualifies for consistency, but you can put it at the beginning in some cases if you like.

Comment: I think I always need it non const atleast.
It's a pointer to my ModuleStructure which is being looped through to set it.
That structure contains the DWORDS: base and size
So it constantly checks if the dll can be loaded and if so it sets is base and size